# Calling multiple services concurrently inside a method

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have a scenario where I am supposed to call 4 different external services inside a method concurrently, and if anyone of the thread will get the data first then I need to cancel the rest of the thread and return the response.

```
class ProductService{
    public List<Product> getProducts(){
       // logic to call multiple services concurrently 
       // if any of the thread get the data then cancel the rest concurrent call gracefully
       // return the response
    }
}
```

Could anybody help me to implement this logic.

Comment: You want to block indefinitely until you receive the first response right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client

```
public Mono<Product> getProduct(String productId) {
  // api request using spring webclient
}
```

Consumer

```
Mono<Product> request1 = getProduct("1");
Mono<Product> request2 = getProduct("2");

Product product = Flux.merge(request1, request2).blockFirst();
```

This will block indefinitely till one of the request returns.
This uses Spring webflux. More on this [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-simultaneous-calls)